# Need help in understanding a section of a paper.

Tags: vector-analysis, gradient-descent, projection

Below is a snapshot of the relevant section in the paper:
[image]

Why does it lead to "From a geometric perspective, the gradient $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$ is the projection of $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \bar{x}}$ onto the tangent space of the unit hyperspace at the normal vector $\bar{x}$." Why and what does this statement mean?

$\bar{x}$ is the normalized vector of x.

The full paper is at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06369.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

It's typical nonsense from bad/confusing notation. $L$ is being used to denote two different functions here, one defined on all of space, one defined on the unit sphere. Let's rewrite. Start with 
$$
L : R^n \to R
$$
and define 
$$
N : R^n \to S^{n-1} : x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|}.
$$
Now let 
$$
H: R^n \to R : x \mapsto L(N(x)).
$$

(This is what the paper means by $L(\bar{x})$.)

Now the chain rule says that 
$$
DH(x) = DL( N(x)) \circ DN(x)
$$
(Here I'm using "DH(x)" to denote the derivative transformation for the function $H$ at the point $x$.)

What is $DN(x)$? Well, in the $x$ direction, it's zero, for $N(cx) = N(x)$ for any $c \ne 0$ and $x \ne 0$. In short: $N$ is constant along rays from the origin. If $v$ is a vector orthogonal to $x$, then $DN(x)[v] = v / \|x \|$, i.e., in directions orthogonal to $x$, $DN(x)$ is just a scaling transformation. Summary: if we pick an orthogonal basis for $R^n$ consisting of 
$$
x, v_1, \ldots, v_{n-1}
$$
where all the $v_i$ are, of course, orthogonal to $x$, hence tangent to the unit sphere at $N(x)$, 
then the matrix of $DN(x)$ in this basis will be 
$$
\pmatrix{
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & k & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & k & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & 0  & k 
}
$$
where $k = \frac{1}{\|x\|}$.

Now the claim --- that $DH$ is the projection of $DL$ onto the tangent space at $N(x)$ --- is a bit clearer, although perhaps a little misleading. For any vector $v$, $DN(x)[v]$ projects $v$ to be perpendicular to $x$, but also scales it by $1/\|x\|$. Then applying $DL$ to that resulting vector is what's mean by "projecting DL onto the tangent space."

***Post-comment addition***:
$$\newcommand{\bx}{{\mathbf x}}\newcommand{\bv}{{\mathbf v}}$$
Let me try to make clear the description of $DN(\bx)$ by an example in 3-space. I'll use a boldface $bx$ to denote the coordinate triple $(x, y, z)$. I'll assume that all points I mention are away from the origin, so that $\| \bx \| > 0$.

The formula for 
$N(\bx)$ is 
$$
N(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}(x, y, z)
$$
The first coordinate is $x(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1/2}$, and the derivatives of that with respect to $x, y,$ and $z$ are
$$
\pmatrix{
(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1/2} - x^2 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-3/2}\\
 -xy(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-3/2}\\
-xz(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-3/2}
} =
(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-3/2} \pmatrix{
( y^2 + z^2)\\
 -xy\\
-xz
}.
$$
The other two terms are similar, yielding
$$
DN(x, y, z) = 
(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-3/2} \pmatrix{
( y^2 + z^2) & -xy & -xz\\
- xy & (x^2  + z^2) & -yz\\
-xz & -yz & (x^2 + y^2)
}.
$$
Let's take $\bx_0 = (0, 3, 0)$, so $\| \bx_0 \| = 3$. Then 
$$
DN(\bx_0) = 
\frac{1}{27} \pmatrix{
9 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 9
} = \frac{1}{3} \pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
}.
$$

This is a linear transformation of 3-space. If we apply it to the vector $\bv_0$ that points in the direction of $\bx_0$, i.e., 
$$
\bv_0 = \pmatrix{0\\ 1\\ 0}
$$
we get
$$
DN(\bx_0)(\bv_0) = 
\frac{1}{27} \pmatrix{
9 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 18 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 9
}\pmatrix{0, 1, 0} = \pmatrix{0\\ 0\\ 0}.
$$
If we pick two more vectors orthogonal to $\bv_0$, namely
$$
\bv_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0}, \bv_2 = \pmatrix{0\\0\\1},
$$
and multiply each by the matrix above, 
we get
$$
DN(\bx_0)[\bv_1] = \frac{1}{3} \bv_1 \\
DN(\bx_0)[\bv_2] = \frac{1}{3} \bv_2,
$$
which you can verify by multiplying out things yourself. 
Thus in the $\bv_0, \bv_1, \bv_2$ basis, the matrix for $DN(\bx_0)$ is 
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{3}& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}}, 
$$
exactly as promised.

Comment: What does DN(x)[v] mean? Does it mean dot product? Shouldn't dot product of orthogonal vectors be 0?

Comment: $DN(x)$ is a linear transformation. When I write $DN(x)[v]$, I mean to apply that transformation to the vector $v$.

Comment: In that case shouldn't, DN(x)[v] = v/||v||? You write v/||x||. I don't quite understand that paragraph.

Comment: See post-comment addition.

Comment: Your example does show that the claim may be true. However, it is not a proof that it is always true, right?

Comment: That's right. It's meant, by showing you the details, to help you see why it's always true. It does, for instance, show that $DN(x)$ is a linear transformation. The statement that $DN(x)[x] = 0$ is evident because $N$ is constant along rays from the origin. The statement that $DN(x)[v]$ is a multiple of $v$, when $v$ is orthogonal to $x$, is evident from the definition. Together, they tell you that the matrix for $DN(x)$, in the kind of basis I described, must have the diagonal form I wrote down. This is basically (1) change of basis formula, (2) geometric identification of eigenvectors.